# XCode/Storyboard:Creating a Modal View

Tags: ios, xcode4, modalviewcontroller

I'm reading through the apple developer library and would like to use a submenu like apple shows in a picture:

[image]

First question: Is that a modal view? And if yes, how to create something like that? Does this submenu has its own controller and view or is all that declared in the view above? I'm using storyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope this is an `UIActionSheet`, it does not have a nib file or a class file, you use it like this

```
UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" 
                                                   delegate:self 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"
                                     destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
[sheet showInView:self.view];

//Function gets called when user taps on a button
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

}
```

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for your information! In the case I want the ActionSheet being popped up when I press the button in the navigationBar - in which controller do I have to write this action?